# ListBox.SelectedIndex binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, listbox

For some strange reason, `ListBox.SelectedIndex` is not working correctly. My ListBox is defined as follows:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedAttachmentIndex}">
```

Both properties `Attachments` and `SelectedAttachmentIndex` are defined in my ViewModel. There are two buttons for adding and removing attachments respectively. These two buttons are bound to two `ICommand` objects of my VM. These commands in turn call `AddAttachment()` and `RemoveAttachment()` functions of my VM.

After adding a new attachment, I want to select it automatically. After removing the attachment, I want to select the new attachment at that index. All of this works fine except for this last requirement, i.e. the ListBox doesn't select the next attachment after removing one. Here is the code for `RemoveAttachment()`:

```
public void RemoveAttachment(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < mDS.Attachment.DefaultView.Count)
    {
        mDS.Attachment.DefaultView[index].Row.Delete();
        mSelectedAttachmentIndex = Math.Min(mDS.Attachment.DefaultView.Count - 1, index);
        RaisePropertyChanged(this, "Attachments");
        RaisePropertyChanged(this, "SelectedAttachmentIndex");
    }
}
```

There's no exception or error. The code works fine and `mSelectedAttachmentIndex` gets correct value, but the ListBox in the UI doesn't select anything. What am I missing?

NOTE: Interestingly, in the case of `AddAttachment()` it correctly selects the newly added item.

Comment: :deleted my answer..!!

Comment: Cool. That was some help for SO servers. ;-)

Comment: Is `mSelectedAttachmentIndex` backup filed for property `SelectedAttachmentIndex`? Also try setting `SelectedAttachmentIndex` to index after remove directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it finally. The `Attachments` property was the culprit. What was happening was that `Attachments` property (which is read-only array of strings) had the following definition:

```
    public string[] Attachments
    {
        get
        {
            return mDS.Attachment.Where(row => row.RowState!= DataRowState.Deleted).Select(row2=>row2.Path).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I was basically using LINQ to create a projection. Now what I did was to RECREATE the string array every time this property was accessed by by the binding, which would in turn empty the bound ListBox for a moment, thus setting the `SelectedIndex` to -1, which would in turn update the value of `SelectedAttachmentIndex` property too. After that the ListBox was getting the new array of strings, but the SelectedIndex was getting lost.

I have now updated my `Attachments` property to return the DataTable directly instead of creating a projection. It all works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for some reason after updating the ItemsSource of ListBox the SelectedIndex prop resets to -1 that is why the result of Math.Min(mDS.Attachment.DefaultView.Count - 1, index) will be always -1. So you can do like:

```
if (index >= 0 && index < mDS.Attachment.DefaultView.Count)
{
    int tempSelInd = index;
    mDS.Attachment.DefaultView[index].Row.Delete();
    mSelectedAttachmentIndex = Math.Min(mDS.Attachment.DefaultView.Count - 1, tempSelInd );
    RaisePropertyChanged(this, "Attachments");
    RaisePropertyChanged(this, "SelectedAttachmentIndex");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was able to figure out that "some reason". Your workaround should work, but I'll stick to correct approach here. See my answer for more details.

Comment: You could do +1 for me :) Good luck!